# How can I prevent the JSON web service response from downloading to a file?

Tags: xml, json, wcf, web-services, rest

I have some WCF service code that is virtually the same, except one method is supposed to return a xml result, and the other a json result:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRestServiceImpl
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "xml/{id}")]
    string XMLData(string id);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "json/{id}")]
    string JSONData(string id);
}
```

The xml works fine (e.g., when I enter "*http://localhost:4841/RestServiceImpl.svc/xml/2468*" into the browser).

However, when I enter "*http://localhost:4841/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/2468*" I get a "*File Download - Security Warning*" dialog, which allows me to save a file (named "2468" in this case), which contains the following when opened in Notepad:

*{"JSONDataResult":"You requested product 2468"}*

Is this "as-designed" (to save json results to a file), or why doesn't it act the same way as the xml-o-rama?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's up to your browser to determine how to handle any particular Content-Type, and it sounds like your browser doesn't know what to do with JSON.

To check this, while using the Chrome Dev Console or Firebug (or whatever equivalent in whatever browser you use), look at the network requests when you load that resource. In the headers, you should see something like

```
Content-type: application/json
```

If you do, the problem is your browser. If you don't see that, your server or service code is wrong (and especially if it's `application/octet-stream` which is the mime-type equivalent of "I have no idea").

As far as browser, personally I recommend Chrome + this excellent plugin for displaying formatted JSON output: https://github.com/callumlocke/json-formatter

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which browser you use to talk to the service. IE (up to IE9) knows how to display XML, but not JSON, which is why it shows one but asks you to save the other (just like when you browse to some binary file). Chrome knows how to display both, so you can browse to both .../json/2468 and .../xml/2468 and it will show the response. There's nothing in the service to be done about that<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually, if what you're interested is to display the output in the browser (and not consume the service by some client which need to understand JSON or XML), you can also return data formatted as HTML. One easy way to do that is to return the HTML as a stream, as shown below.

```
public class StackOverflow_12940785
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IRestServiceImpl
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "xml/{id}")]
        string XMLData(string id);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "json/{id}")]
        string JSONData(string id);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "html/{id}")]
        Stream HTMLData(string id);
    }
    public class Service : IRestServiceImpl
    {
        public string XMLData(string id)
        {
            return "You requested product " + id;
        }

        public string JSONData(string id)
        {
            return "You requested product " + id;
        }

        public Stream HTMLData(string id)
        {
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/html";
            string response = @"<html>
                <head><title>My service</title></head>
                <body>
                    <p>You requested <b>product " + id + @"</b></p>
                </body>
            </html>";
            return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response));
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://" + Environment.MachineName + ":8000/Service";
        WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri(baseAddress));
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Host opened");

        Console.Write("Press ENTER to close the host");
        Console.ReadLine();
        host.Close();
    }
}
```